# Create a dummy matrix where values from a column in a df are put into a matrix and where value exist = 1 and the rest =NA or 0

Tags: r, matrix

### Description of problem:

I have a time serie data with 11640 rows where each row is the measured watertable at that certain hour.
I'm in need of a code that take my column with watertable values (name of the the certain column in my Dataset is: "Watertable") and put it into different columns in a Matrix. The columns in "Watertable" contains depth values from 0 to over 100. I'm only interested in the values that is from 1 to 120 cm.

I have created the matrix with the same row length (i.e. 11640 rows) and with 120 columns where each column represent depth below surface (e.g. column 35 (named X35) is 35 cm below surface) (all column names are 1 to 120 with an X in front of the number: X1, X2, X3, X4... X119, X120).
Now I want to put my values in my "Watertable" into the corresponding column in my matrix.

### Example:

if the "Watertable" value for a certain row is 58. I want to have all columns in my matrox that is 58 and higher set to 1 (and the lower ones set to NA or 0). OBS! As my data has decimal values, I want to "round up" if .5 and "round down" if <.5 ---> 50.56781 = 51    and 50.34369 = 50

Example of "Watertable" data:

```
> head(DATA1)
  DATE_TIME             Watertable
1 2014-06-14 00:00:00   50.80874
2 2014-06-14 01:00:00   50.04499
3 2014-06-14 02:00:00   50.02677
4 2014-06-14 03:00:00   51.01249
5 2014-06-14 04:00:00   51.04969
6 2014-06-14 05:00:00   51.56349
```

What I want:

```
Date                   X1          ...          X50       X51     ...
2014-06-14 00:00:00    NA or 0     NA or 0      1         1       1
2014-06-14 01:00:00    NA or 0     NA or 0      1         1       1
2014-06-14 02:00:00    NA or 0     NA or 0      1         1       1
2014-06-14 03:00:00    NA or 0     NA or 0      NA or 0   1       1
2014-06-14 04:00:00    NA or 0     NA or 0      NA or 0   1       1
2014-06-14 05:00:00    NA or 0     NA or 0      NA or 0   NA or 0 1
```

I have also one column with Date and time in my matrix as I thought I'll need that one in my code

Codefor my matrix:

```
WT_U_mtx= matrix(NA, nrow=11640, ncol=101, byrow=FALSE)
s= seq(from=0, to=100, by=1)
colnames(WT_U_mtx) = s
WT_U_mtx= as.data.frame(WT_U_mtx)
names(WT_U_mtx) <-  sub("", "X", names(WT_U_mtx))          
WT_U_mtx= cbind(WT_U_mtx, DATA[,"DATE_TIME"])
```

Look of raw matrix

> tbl_df(WT_U_mtx)
>   Source: local data frame [11,640 x 122]

```
      X0    X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9    X10   X11  
1     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    
2     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    
3     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA        
4     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA      
5     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA      
6     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA      
7     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA      
8     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA      
9     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA      
10    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA      
 ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   
Variables not shown: X13 (lgl),X14 (lgl),X15 (lgl),X16 (lgl),X17 (lgl),
X18 (lgl), X19 (lgl), X20 (lgl), ..., X120 (lgl), DATA[, "DATE_TIME"] (time)
```

My try: I have actually **no clue how to write the code** and I have been looking everywhere on the internet (including other questions on stackoverflow). I assume I want some kind of "If" function. My apologies if the question isn't clear or incorrect in structure, I'm a rookie to this webpage and Rstudio overall.

Appreciate all help I can get!
/Elin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make up data:

```
dd <- read.csv(text="
time,water.table
2014-06-14 00:00:00,50.80874
2014-06-14 01:00:00,50.04499
2014-06-14 02:00:00,50.02677
2014-06-14 03:00:00,51.01249
2014-06-14 04:00:00,51.04969
2014-06-14 05:00:00,51.56349")
dd$time <- as.POSIXct(dd$time)
```

Put together matrix:

```
maxlen <- 120
r <- round(dd$water.table)
m <- sapply(r,function(x) rep(0:1,c(x-1,maxlen-x+1)))
m <- t(m)
```

Check:

```
dim(m) ## 6 120
apply(m==0,1,sum)  ## number of zeros in each row
## [1] 50 49 49 50 50 51
```

Combine:

```
dd2 <- data.frame(dd,m)
```

Comment: Moahaha! I just love this! Thank you so much! I realised what was wrong when I tried your code (that is why I deleted those comments); I had values that was above 120 but I changed the length to 300 instead and I got a very beautiful matrix with the info I wanted! Wonderful! 

Thnkas again!